# my main.css is not rendering,I am using multiple entry points webpack.config

Tags: django, vue.js, vuetify.js, django-webpack-loader

My `main.css` is not rendering,I am using multiple entry points in `webpack.config.js` file

```
% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable' content='yes' />
  <meta itemprop='name' content='TableGrabber Dashboard'>
  {% render_bundle "main" "css" %}
  {% render_bundle "vendors~main" "css" %}
  <title>
    {{ title }}
  </title>
```

I expect my both app.js file will render and the routes written in them can be run by putting the URL in the browser

Answer (score 0):

you forgotten to put `{% render_bundle 'back_office' 'js' %}` in the body of your part of the html file

your file could look like this

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- YOU COULD INCLUDE STATIC CSS FILES LIKE ... -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='{% static "/css/fontawesome5.8.1/all.min.css" %}'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='{% static "/css/bootstrap4.3.1/bootstrap.min.css" %}'>

    <title>YOUR TITLE</title>

    {% render_bundle 'first_entry_point' 'css' %}
  </head>
   <body>
    <!-- YOU COULD INCLUDE STATIC JS FILES LIKE JQUERY ... -->
    <script src='{% static "/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" %}' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='{% static "/js/bootstrap4.3.1/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" %}' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="react-app" style="height:100%;"></div>
    {% render_bundle 'first_entry_point' 'js' %}
  </body>
</html>
```

and in the `webpack.config.js` you could have the entrypoints like

```
.
.
.
module.exports = {

  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    first_entry_point: path.join(__dirname, "...first_entry_point..."),
    second_entry_point: path.join(__dirname, "...second_entry_point...")
  },
.
.
.
```

Comment: thanks,but now nothing is rendering on my browser & there is no errror on console my entry looks like app: ['./dashboard/src/app.js'], app2: ['./backoffice/templates/app.js'] should i have to any modification in base.html also,then what?